# Does Substrate do special things with Option types in Storage?

Tags: storage, substrate

I understand that Substrate will return the 0 or null value when Storage is queried for a key that doesn't exist. Does it do something special with Option types?

I ask because in the default node-template, the storage item Something is declared as

```
Something: Option<u32>;
```

But later in the `do_something` setter, the method signature declares `something: u32`, but passes it directly without wrapping it in `Some()`:

```
Something::put(something);
```

instead of

```
Something::put(Some(something));
```

If Substrate is interpreting a call to store `T` as storing `Some<T>`, does that also mean if I store `None` in a map against a key then it will delete the key? Is it storing `Some(T)` or `T`?

Or is it just that Rust is building a specialised method call for `Something::put(some: T)` case as well as `Something::put(some: Option<T>)`?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed `decl_storage` expand differently if the value is an Option or not.

The trait implemented is [srml_support::storage::StorageValue](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v1.0/srml_support/storage/trait.StorageValue.html)

- if the value is `Option<MyType>` the trait implemented is

```rust
srml_support::storage::StorageValue<MyType> {
    type Query = Option<MyType>;
}
```

in the implementation `get` will return None if no value is found in the trie at the key used by this storage.

- if the value is not an option but whatever other type `MyType` the trait implemented is

```rust
srml_support::storage::StorageValue<MyType> {
    type Query = MyType;
}
```

in the implementation `get` will return Default if no value is found in the trie at the key used by this storage.

Note that this default can be overriden using the syntax:

```rust
NotOptionSomething: u32 = MyDifferentDefault;
```

> If Substrate is interpreting a call to store T as storing Some, does that also mean if I store None in a map against a key then it will delete the key? Is it storing Some(T) or T?

At this point this is no longer substrate interpretation but just a rust trait implementation. The `put` function is implemented to store the encoded value in the trie. Not wrapped in an option.

Comment: Thank you  for the detail here, can you just clarify that last para: so a map K => Option<T> always stores T or removes the key? i.e. no difference at all between ::insert(key,None) and ::remove(key)?

Comment: @PhilH if you write `MyStorage: map K => Option<T> ` the trait implemented will be:

`pub trait StorageMap<K, T> {
    type Query = Option<T>
    ...
}`

So there is no method such as `:insert(key, None)` the only insert method does take `T` as argument.

But indeed if you want to "store" None then you can do `::remove(key)`, though you didn't stored None on chain you just literally removed the value and None is returned when there is no value.

Key point is `StorageMap<Key, Value> { type Query ... }` when option we implement the trait with `Query=Option<Value>`